# Short permalink to answer doesn't work after merge

Tags: bug, merge

[How to skip to create Ubuntu Menu in status bar?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129761/how-to-skip-to-create-ubuntu-menu-in-status-bar)
was merged with
[How to get global application menu for gvim?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132977/how-to-get-global-menu-for-gvim).
After this, the short permalink to one of the answers still referred to the old question.

- [Answer 129764](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132977/how-to-get-global-menu-for-gvim#129764)

  - https://askubuntu.com/a/129764/32651 <--- Worked
- [Answer 132581](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132977/how-to-get-global-menu-for-gvim#132581)

  - https://askubuntu.com/a/132581/32651 <--- Didn't work

The problem seems to be that the server sends a "301 Moved Permanently" when accessing the short link. According to

- [Firefox 5 'caching' 301 redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980192/firefox-5-caching-301-redirects)

this is a cacheable response.
Since I had already accessed the short link before the merge, it was probably cached in my browser as a redirect to the pre-merge location of the answer.

Some other response code might be more appropriate:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection